# Chat link broken with [chat] as well as in dropdown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, magic-links

In two different ways, the resolution of "chat" to the site specific chat is broken.

First, if you leave a comment with [chat] in it on a site, it will resolve to the name of the site but link to generic chat.stackexchange.

See [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12712/how-best-to-communicate-an-fyi-a-meeting-is-taking-place#comment120554_12712):
 [image]

Notice that the name autoresolved in this case but the link did not.

Additionally, when selecting the "Chat" link from the dropdown, it defaults to the same generic chat.stackexchange:

[image]

When clicking this, I am not directed to the site chatrooms for UX, but rather Workplace:

[image]

Also note that if I manually navigate to "Favorites" then the next time I do this, I instead of seeing that I see the Favorites view:

[image]
Both these should resolve differently than they currently do.

Comment: Testing [chat].

Comment: The referrer header is used to detect where the user is coming from and based on this, show only relevant rooms. When you click the link, what rooms you see? This is what matters, not how the link looks like.

Comment: @ShadowWizard when I tested on ux.SE, I only see the four rooms I am currently in. If I go to the "Site" tab on chat, selecting chat from the menu presents me with all the site chat rooms for The Workplace - not UX.

Comment: Not sure I got it. If you click "chat" in top bar of ux.SE site, you see rooms of Workplace?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see whatever my last viewed tab was (from chat.stackexchange). In my case, the last site chat I viewed appears to be The Workplace chat.

Comment: Sorry, can't figure what the bug is, but hope a dev can - sounds like something is off with the referrer check, somehow.

Comment: hmm... do you have security software that might be messing with the headers sent by your browser to the server? This might explain those weird issues.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe, I can check when I get home on my Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We examine the referrer  to see what Q&A site you came from and use that to show you site-specific rooms:

[image]

I just tested this with several combinations of tabs/referring sites and we always show the "site" tab, regardless of what tab was shown before.

Please elaborate on what you mean by "generic chat.stackexchange" and include the steps you're taking to reproduce this (ideally along with screenshots).

Comment: I'll update my post with some screenshots, one sec

Comment: 20 seconds passed already, @enderland ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh fine it was something like 60 seconds (Anna I updated)

Comment: Just a wild guess @Anna, but what happens when referrer is blank/blocked? Do you show the last active site perhaps?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No referrer, no smart guessing. That would put this in the "status-bydesign" category.

Comment: Weird, not sure why my work machine is doing that..